# Error con dialog: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Tags: android, diálogo

Al intentar abrir un dialog en mi aplicacion me salta ese error.

"You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

He buscado y parece ser un fallo entre el manifest.xml y styles.xml pero no consigo  hacerlo funcionar.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:278)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
        at com.enzo.practicaplataforma.ConsultaActivity$2.onItemLongClick(ConsultaActivity.java:138)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2972)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Este es el manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_j23"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_j23_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".EdicionModulo"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Portada" />
    <activity android:name=".ConsultaActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

Archivo styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Codigo del dialog que intento abrir:

```
lvListaModulos.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                alerta.setMessage("¿Desea marcar este modulo como aprobado?").setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ConsultaActivity.class);

                                gp.actualizarTabla("'Aprobado'", id);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog titulo = alerta.create();
                titulo.setTitle("Editar" + nModulo);
                titulo.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te sugiero limpies y construyas tu proyecto, me parece que la configuración es correcta

Comment: Perfecto! ya me ha funcionado, con limpiar y contruir el proyecto ha ido todo correcto. Muchas gracias, Jorge.

Comment: Si @Enzo tu configuración en realidad era correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad la configuración es correcta, el tema definido a tu Activity:

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   ...
   ...
    <activity android:name=".ConsultaActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

En realidad desciende de `Theme.AppCompat`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Lo cual es correcto.

Asegura limpiar y construir nuevamente tu proyecto para que tome la configuración adecuada.